# User Instance Failure error when creating a Service-based database in VS 2008 and using SQL Server Express 2005 on Windows 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-7, sql-server-express

I just installed SQL-Server Express 2005 on my machine and I am trying to create a Service-based Database for a C# application.  But when I try to create it I end up with the following error message:

```
Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance.
The connection will be closed.
```

I'm completely new to SQL-Sever and C#, so what do I need to do to fix this problem?
(I'm coming from a MySQL/Java background.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay found the solution.  Since I was using Windows7 I had to delete that directory from

C:\Users\leeand00\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS instead.

Thanks all!

Comment: It would have been courteous to give credit (/accepted answer) to DataPimp's answer here; he clearly indicated exactly where the problem was, give or take the users's profile location.

Comment: @Marc, I found the same answer that Data Pimp gave me (before Data Pimp gave me it), on another website, but it was not Windows 7 specific.

Answer (score 21):

Try deleting the files in the "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS instead." folder.

Comment: @DataPimp I'm running Windows 7 and this directory does not exist.

Comment: Can I ask why you choose to install 2005 instead of 2008?

Comment: Sorry I dont have win7 so I really reaching here but have you installed the latest Service Pack?  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ae7387c3-348c-4faa-8ae5-949fdfbe59c4&displaylang=en

Comment: No I don't think I have that installed...hmmm

Comment: So how was the accepted answer any different that what I posted?

Comment: @DataPimp I found this same answer several other places (notably the Head First C# Forum).  I just didn't know what the answer was for Windows 7, it's probably actually a different question (where did they move the "documents and settings" folder to?)  I gave you an upvote anyway though. Sorry for the Drama.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *`AttachDbFilename`* attribute in connection string like this:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=PATH/YOURDB.mdf;Integrated
Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

then you need to enable **user instance** in SQL Server 2005 Express edition. Open SQL Server Management Studio Express or SQL Server Console and run following commands:

```
exec sp_configure 'user instances enabled', 1
reconfigure
```

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot It said that 'user instances' was changed from 1 to 1, and that I should run the reconfigure command (which I did as a separate query per your example.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Then I got the same error message when I tried to create the Service-based Database again.

Comment: @leeand00 then there may be something Windows 7 specific problem with this